# Can i have customized Edittext properties for my customized edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to work with validations.For that I would like to give my type of validation as an attribute/property while am creating my EditText field.

```
android:inputType="email"
```

my customized is

```
validation:requiredType="phone"
```

in my edit text field how can I achieve this in Eclipse.

Comment: you want only numbers only in EditText?

Comment: android:inputType="0123456789"

Comment: no i would like to several validation types.ex: creditcard,decimal num,default status,reg ex , password with diff chars.like that

Comment: You can check value after like this  private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
public abstract class TextValidator
        implements TextWatcher {

    private final TextView textView;

    public TextValidator(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    public abstract void validate(TextView textView, String text);

    @Override
    final public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        validate(textView, text);
    }

    @Override
    final public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { 
        /* Don't care */
    }

    @Override
    final public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        /* Don't care */
    }
}
```

Just use it like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextValidator(editText) {
    @Override
    public void validate (TextView textView, String text){ 
        /* Validation code here */
    }
});
```

To create a library:

File > New Module

select Android Library

To use the library add it as a dependancy:

File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies

Then add the module (android library) as a module dependency.

Run your project. It will work.

hope it helps

Comment: yes offcourse,but i need to create lib for this.by that need to use future purpose.dont want to write every time.